# how to make a horizontal line-to till the end width of svg?

Tags: svg, path

how to draw a horizontal path to the end width of svg?
I don't want specific pixel.
I want it auto fix to any svg width.

```
<svg width="100%" height="300">
          <path d="M0 0 H 100 " stroke="black">
</svg>
```

Comment: Use a <line> element.

Comment: use `<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke="black"/>`